SSH hanging with Raspberry Pi
I have a RaspberryPi Model 3A+, with the Raspbian OS installed. I am trying to SSH from my laptop, into my Pi over my LAN.
Initially I encountered no issues. I could ssh in fine, execute commands, etc. Now, when I try to SSH in, I find my ssh attempt is hanging.
Attempting to debug, I run:
ssh -vvvvv username@LAN.address

Which returns (with some edits):
( This webpage flags the error message as spam so I am linking to my original post - see there for more information regarding the error message I received: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517092/ssh-hanging-with-raspberry-pi )
After this, the connection hangs, and my local terminal freezes - even entering CTRL+Z does not recover control.
Bizarrely, on the odd occassion, the ssh completes successfully and I am presented with an interactive shell. After several seconds, however, this shell then freezes. The vast majority of attempts result in ssh hanging at the above described point, before an interactive shell is reached.
I found this post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271950/ssh-command-hangs-indefinitely , which appears to match my issue, however none of the fixes proposed there seem to work.
I tried the netcat approach:
ssh -vvvvv -o "ProxyCommand nc %h %p" username@LAN.address

And the following approah:
ssh -o IPQoS=0 username@LAN.address

Both hang at the same point.
In all my testing above, I have been running a separate terminal pinging my RPi. The ping connection has never ceased, so network connectivity does not appear to be the issue.
What could be causing this inconsistency ?
System info
My laptop specs are:
Linux: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (focal)
Bash: 5.0.017(1)
I am re-posting here after not encountering luck on the AskUbuntu site.
EDIT
The output of systemctl status ssh following a ssh attempt that hanged, and a successful ssh, is:
 ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-06-14 17:23:24 BST; 1 day 1h ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 457 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 537 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 407)
        CPU: 4.295s
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─537 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Jun 15 18:15:48 raspberrypi sshd[28780]: Accepted password for userName from IPADDRESS port 46006 ssh2
Jun 15 18:15:48 raspberrypi sshd[28780]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userName(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 15 18:17:17 raspberrypi sshd[28807]: Accepted password for userName from IPADDRESS port 55168 ssh2
Jun 15 18:17:17 raspberrypi sshd[28807]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userName(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 15 18:17:38 raspberrypi sshd[28826]: Accepted password for userName from IPADDRESS port 39180 ssh2
Jun 15 18:17:38 raspberrypi sshd[28826]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userName(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 15 18:20:15 raspberrypi sshd[28869]: Accepted password for userName from IPADDRESS port 33982 ssh2
Jun 15 18:20:15 raspberrypi sshd[28869]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userName(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 15 18:21:48 raspberrypi sshd[28958]: Accepted password for userName from IPADDRESS port 39032 ssh2
Jun 15 18:21:48 raspberrypi sshd[28958]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user userName(uid=1000) by (uid=0)

The settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config_conf are:
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Nothing here looks suspicious to me - does anyone else see any issues ?
I ran iw wlan0 set power_save off, but this has not solved the issue.

Check systemctl status ssh on the Pi to see if there are any clues there.

I hesitate to even mention this, but,,,  My RPi 3A+ runs the 64-bit RPi OS 'bookworm'. I had WiFi/network issues not very different from what you've described. I disabled WiFi 'power save', and my problems "went away" ? :-|  If you want to try it: sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off.

Review the SSH configuration on both your laptop and the Raspberry Pi. Check the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the Raspberry Pi for any unusual settings.

Thanks all for the comments - no luck with any of the suggestions. I have added further details to the post above.
